# How to use Jest to test higher order function for Redux action with nested function

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, higher-order-functions

I am using Jest to test a Redux action function fn1.  fn1 is a higher order function that wraps fn2.  My test is just to make sure fn2 is called when fn1 is executed.  Doesn't seems to work.  I am thinking about using `jest.spyOn`, but it doesn't seem to make sense.

> myActions.js:

```
export const fn1 = obj => {
  return strInput => {
    fn2(strInput, obj);
  };
};

export const fn2 = (strInput, obj) => ({name:strInput, obj});
```

myAction.test.js:

```
import {fn1, fn2} from myAction.test.js

it("should call fn2", () => {
    fn1({test:"test"})("David")
    expect(fn2).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In a way, I feel what you're trying to do is testing an implementation detail and not the API of the function, but in unit testing, you really want to be testing, or asserting, the correct output based upon a specified input, i.e. `f(x) = y`, testing input `x` yields output `y`.

Presumably your `fn2` will have its own unit test, so you can assume it is tested and correct when it's used in other functions, like `fn1`.

Here's how I would test `fn1`:

```
it("should compute composed value", () => {
  expect(fn1({ test: "test" })("David")).toEqual({
    name: "David",
    obj: { test: "test" }
  });
});
```

[image: Edit interesting-shtern-uqofl]

I would say the typical use-case for spying on, or asserting, a function call is the case of callbacks. Callbacks aren't part of the implementation of a function, but usually an external side-effect.

```
const fn3 = (value, callback) => {
  // bunch of code logic
  callback(value);
  // more code logic
  return true;
};

it("should callback function", () => {
  const cb = jest.fn();
  fn3(3, cb);
  expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
});
```

**Not really part of the answer but informative**

At this point I want to point out an error in nomenclature: Higher Order Function vs Currying

A [Higher Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) is one that takes as input a function and returns a new function. Examples include `.map`, `.filter`, functional composition

```js
const plus3 = x => x + 3; // a first order function
const double = (fn, v) => fn(v) * 2; // a higher order function

const plus3AndDouble = x => double(plus3, x); // a (decorated) first order function

console.log(plus3AndDouble(0)); // (0 + 3) * 2 = 6
console.log(plus3AndDouble(1)); // (1 + 3) * 2 = 8
```

What you've accomplished is *actually* a concept called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) wherein you take a function that takes multiple inputs and convert it to a sequence of functions each taking a single input.

```js
const foo = (a, b, c) => a + b * c;
const bar = a => b => c => foo(a, b, c);

console.log(foo(1, 2, 3) === bar(1)(2)(3)); // true
```